# Is WebAssign ADA compliant?

Tags: homework, online-instruction, disability

I hope this is a good place to ask about this. My institution uses WebAssign for homework in many classes. A concern has come up about being compliant with [ADA](http://www.dol.gov/dol/topic/disability/ada.htm). From [a page on the WebAssign site](http://www.webassign.net/manual/student_guide/c_a_accessibility.htm), it sounds like WebAssign should be ok. But I have also found a reference to [a lawsuit](https://nfb.org/images/nfb/documents/pdf/miami%20teach.pdf) (from 2014?) indicating that there are "problems".

My question is basically if anyone knows whether WebAssign is ADA compliant. Before I start spending hours research this, I wanted to see if anyone has some insight.

Comment: You might consider asking a legal forum or a forum addressing User Interface issues or even a forum dealing with disabled people and their caretakers.  If you crosspost, please add links to the other fora.  Gerhard "Good Luck With Your Question" Paseman, 2015.07.21

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: I had thought about that. I thought a forum for math teachers would be the best place since they would have to deal with this issue. I will give it a bit of time here.

Comment: Of note: the lawsuit isn't just one unhappy student: [the US Justice Department filed a motion to join the lawsuit](http://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/justice-department-moves-intervene-disability-discrimination-lawsuit-alleging-miami).

Comment: WebAssign isn't the only program that case had issues with. Other resources listed include PDFs, GoogleDocs, Youtube, Vimeo, TurnItIn, Powerpoint, and library books.

Comment: At http://www.w3.org/WAI/eval/Overview.html you find tools to evaluate the accessibility of a website. Maybe your want to ask you question on http://ux.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: The specific problem with webassign cited in the lawsuit is that it uses graphs and figures that are not accessible. MyStatLab sounds even worse -- it's flash-based. I assume the same applies to MyMathLab. There are open-source alternatives, including Lon-Capa, WebWork, and my own Spotter http://www.lightandmatter.com/spotter/spotter.html . The open-source software also has the advantage that students can use it without paying exploitative fees every semester that they take a math course.