# Teaching visually impaired mathematics students

Tags: undergraduate-education, disability

How can typical undergraduate mathematics teaching resources be made accessible to visually impaired students?

Comment: This is not a question I am directly interested in now, but my hope is that it will become a useful resource. It is inspired by http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/what-accessibility-is-available-to-the-blind-and-visually-impaired-students-and and, to a lesser degree, http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/is-webassign-ada-compliant .

Comment: Related: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/is-webassign-ada-compliant . A big culprit in preventing accessibility seems to be non-accessible software such as mymathlab and webassign; there are free and open-source alternatives that don't have the accessibility problems. Another big barrier is books that aren't properly digitized. Tactile graphics may be necessary. A lot of this stuff seems to be expensive and labor-intensive to provide, so it seems that an underlying issue is that the school needs to spend enough money and hire enough people.

Comment: This might be useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.08977

Answer (score 2):

One person who has published on this subject is Emma Cliffe. A couple of the points she makes are:

1. There are difficulties here that are specific to mathematics. It is likely that no one person's job description will cover all the aspects that need to be considered, so any plans should preferably be made together by the student, disability officers and members of the mathematics department.
2. Not many computer file formats of mathematics can be meaningfully converted to accessible resources. As things currently stand, those that are are:
   a) well-formatted word-processed documents with equations entered in the correct format;
   b) well-formatted Latex using a limited range of packages;
   c) html with MathJax.

Comment: Could you give a reference to any relevant publication by Cliffe? If I was listing accessible formats, MathML would be at the top of the list. MathJax is a kludgy workaround for browsers that don't properly support MathML.

Comment: This answer is meant as a stub - hence the CW.